# Obtain ComboBox Items from several TextBoxes

Tags: wpf, combobox, textbox

In WPF, how do I place Text of TextBox into Items of a ComboBox?
I have seen a question that does the opposite, meaning binding selected Item in ComboBox to TextBox.
Here is my scenario, I have a tabcontrol, each tabPage contains TextBoxes. I have already completed data binding for validating the TextBoxes' Text. Now, I need to make the ComboBox outside the tabControl, to display validated Text from TextBoxes.

```
<Grid>
<TabControl>
<TabItem>
<TextBox />
<TextBox>
  ...
</TextBox>
</TabItem>
</TabControl>
<ComboBox   />
<ComboBox   />
</Grid>
```

I'm a fresh newbie to WPF. I may need a lot of references for further reading regarding the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that will display the text of the four textboxes in the combobox:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Name="tb0" />
    <TextBox Name="tb1" Grid.Row="1" />
    <TextBox Name="tb2" Grid.Row="2" />
    <TextBox Name="tb3" Grid.Row="3" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="4">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tb0, Path=Text}" />
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tb1, Path=Text}" />
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tb2, Path=Text}" />
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tb3, Path=Text}" />
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**Edit**:
To hide the items in the combobox when they're empty you can use a converter and check if the text is empty.

Converter:

```
public abstract class BaseConverter : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class StringToVisibilityConverter : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString() != string.Empty ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Add the converter as a resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <TestProject:StringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="stringToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Use the converter:

```
<ComboBoxItem>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tb3, Path=Text}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=tb3, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource stringToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</ComboBoxItem>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I noticed that the combobox shows empty Items in its dropdown list. Next thing is to make it not display blank Items. Suggestions are welcome.